# How to display the value of all the variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am learning how to write Makefile. I found the .VARIABLES variable which holds all the variables valid in Makefile.

I can check the variables' name with command like this:

```
test:
    @echo "${.VARIABLES}" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

But I don't know how to should the values of them. Can anyone teach me to to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to should the values" ?

Comment: for i in .VARIABLES;do echo $i;done;

Comment: @V_Maenolis Sorry, your solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make, then you can use a crafty combination of foreach and .VARIABLES like this:

```
test:
    $(foreach var,$(.VARIABLES),$(info $(var) = $($(var))))
```

Comment: You don't need the eval for this. It works fine without that here.

Comment: @harmic Thanks, that's what I need. But one more question about your answer. You use "info", it works, but why "echo" doesn't work?

Comment: @enchanter You can use echo, but you would need to put it outside the foreach loop, like this: `@echo -e $(foreach var,$(.VARIABLES),"$(var)=$($(var))\n")`. $(foreach...) concatenates all of the values from the loop, and then executes the result. But info has the advantage that there is no need to spawn a subshell.

Comment: This does NOT work when you have MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules